# Interactive computation of spatial data on a web-map

Tags: data, web-mapping

All the GIS area is very new to me so I would like to ask about a guidance of my next steps.

---

### This is the web-map I would like to make (if it is possible):

Lets consider the following map:

[image: EGNOS Computation points].

Each cross represents spatial data in form of point. A number between 1-100 is associated to each point. Any other given point on the map is situated inside an imaginary square defined by the 4 closest spatial data points. For that given point, I would like to display a value witch is computed by linear interpolation of the 4 values of the square corners.

So I would like to show for example:

*lat: 43.9 deg; long: 18.1 deg, approx. value: 35.5%*

[image: map with feature]

Is it possible to create such map? At which layer I should define the interpolation algorithm?

Comment: Any particular software that you are using?

Comment: @Martin - I recently got familiar with PostGIS, GeoServer and GeoExplorer. The Desktop GIS is QGIS.